# selecting from sql

Tags: sql, xml

```
<suggestions>
 <suggestion>
  <description>plate.</description> 
 </suggestion>
 <suggestion>
 <description>snack.</description> 
 </suggestion>
</suggestions>

DECLARE @Suggestions TABLE (
     [Description] VARCHAR(800)
   )
```

I have above xml in a XML type varible in my stored procedure
how can i insert each text between description tags
in to the table @Suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<suggestions>
 <suggestion>
  <description>plate.</description> 
 </suggestion>
 <suggestion>
 <description>snack.</description> 
 </suggestion>
</suggestions>'

DECLARE @Suggestions TABLE ([Description] VARCHAR(800))

INSERT INTO @Suggestions
    SELECT
        Sugg.value('(description)[1]', 'varchar(800)')
    FROM
        @input.nodes('/suggestions/suggestion') AS Tbl(Sugg)

SELECT * FROM @Suggestions
```

The `@input.nodes()` expression basically turns each `<suggestion>` node into a row in the "pseudo" table called `Tbl(Sugg)`. From those "rows" (each basically another XML fragment), you then select out the value you're interested in - here the contents of the `<description>` XML element inside that XML fragment.

Comment: +1 I was going to post a similar answer... then the phone rang :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ-to-XML to get all suggestions, then you can insert that data into the table.